# Programmatically how to know device service type like its CDMA/GSM/GPRS

Tags: blackberry

I am trying to find a code that with help me to find out the device serive-type like CDMA / GSM . I have tried the code below but not helped.

```
DeviceInfo.getDeviceName();
```

Answer (score 5):

You're looking for the RadioInfo class:

```
if(RadioInfo.getNetworkType() == RadioInfo.NETWORK_CDMA) {
    // Do something specific for CDMA
}
```

There are several network constants in RadioInfo, all prefixed with NETWORK_.  See the docs linked to below for more details.

[RadioInfo JavaDocs for 4.5](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.5.0api/net/rim/device/api/system/RadioInfo.html)